# Angular directive bind event and pass parameter to controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive that binds and event to input file elements, and calls a function on the controller

```
appFuncionario.directive('onFileChange', function () {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

         var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.onFileChange);
         //this is where I want to send the parameter
         element.on('change', onChangeHandler);

         element.on('$destroy', function () {
            element.off();
         });

      }
   };
});


<input ng-show="campo.codTipoCampo === 'InputFile'" id="{{campo.id}}" type="file" campo="{{campo}}" on-file-change="uploadFile" />

 //Function in the controller - this is where I want to get a parameter from the directive
 $scope.uploadFile = function (parameter) {

        //do something here
};
```

I need to pass a parameter from the object where the directive is in, to the function executed by the directive on the change event.

I know I can use something like this `campo="{{campo}}"` on the element, and catch it like this `attrs.campo` on the directive, but I can't figure it out how to do this binding

```
element.on('change', onChangeHandler);
```

passing a parameter - I always get this error

> jqLite#on() does not support the `selector` or `eventData`.

Here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2nqQ8oDriHxKcvubnK7l?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for? I'm trying to figure out the bigger picture here as to why you're trying to stuff in variables in the directive level and not just using the controller for what it is intended for but take a look at the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/0zx58hch/) below and lmk if that's what you're looking for.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('fiddle', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.teste = function(campo) {
    alert("Campo: " + campo);
  };
  
});

app.directive('onFileChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.onFileChange);
      element.on('change', function() {
       onChangeHandler(attrs.campo);
      });

      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        element.off();
      });

    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fiddle">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <!-- 
      Attribute campo is the variable stuffed into the 
      controller function via the directive on change event
    -->
    <input type="file" campo="{{'I did it!'}}" on-file-change="teste" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the downvoter want to explain why they downvoted? It would be greatly appreciated.